# Laravel 5.x Voyager manipulate output bread template edit-add and read

Tags: laravel, admin, laravel-blade, voyager

I am trying to manipulate the bread templates of the laravel voyager package. I have to put some new buttons to the templates.

i ve set up a route for the new admin page:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();

    Route::get('order-payment-txns', 'AdminController@orderList')->middleware('admin.user');

});


//Controller

  public function orderList(){
      return view('vendor/tcg/browse-order')
                ->with("alert", "error.voucher_code_wrong");
    }
```

How could it work with the right dataset?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing so wrong. 
copy the original browse, edit-add pages. After that paste to the 
**Resources\Views\Vendor\Voyager\BREAD NAME**

If you dont have voyager folder just create. 
**"BREAD NAME"** section is which page you want to edit. if you want to edit admin\news

Create **Resources\Views\Vendor\Voyager\News\browse.blade.php**
paste original browse codes in here. Edit it.

Comment: great! hadn't thought that this could be so simple! gracias

Comment: Nice to have helped you. :)